# gmap3 don't work on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

gmap3 doesn't work on my website and I don't know why, can someone help me to find the error ?

"I need to add some words to publish my question, so don't read that line sorry"

here is my link:

```
http://www.booclin.ovh/site/plan.html
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    <html lang="fr">
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>    <div style="background:#fff; font-size:1.2rem; line-height:1.8em; padding-top:300px;color:#282828; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:999999999999999; position:fixed; text-align:center;">    <div style='margin:0px 20px 0 20px; width:100%; max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; '>Vous utilisez une ancienne version d'Internet Explorer. Pour des raisons de sécurité, vous devez mettre à jour votre navigateur. S'il vous plaît aller dans "mises à jour de Windows" et installer la dernière version. Merci    </div>    </div>    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en" class="lt-ie9">     <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>    <![endif]-->
<head>    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>    </title>
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="LANGUAGE" content="FR">
<meta name="SUBJECT" content="">
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="All">
<meta name="OWNER" content="">
<meta name="RATING" content="">
<meta name="COPYRIGHT" content="">
<meta name="expires" content="never">
<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="index">
<meta name="Slurp" content="index">
<meta name="MSNBot" content="index">
<meta name="ICBM" content="">
<meta name="Identifier-URL" content="">
<link property="stylesheet" rel="canonical" href=""/>

<link property="stylesheet"  type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
<link property="stylesheet"  type="image/x-icon" rel="icon"          href=""/>
<link property="stylesheet"                      rel="image_src"     href=""/>
<meta property="og:image"                                         content=""/>
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index/css/style.css">
<link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index/font/font.css"/>

</head>




<body>
<div class="left part">

<div style="border:80px solid #fff; width:500px;height:500px;" id="adresse" class="gmap3">    </div>

</div>





<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">    </script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index/js/gmap3.js">    </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#adresse').gmap3({marker:{address: "Apple Store, Saint-Laurent-du-Var, France"},
map:{options:{zoom: 17}
}
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your console log you have an: `Google Maps API error:  MissingKeyMapError`

Comment: maybe you're right, I enter any Google Map API, I don't find where if you check my code ?

Comment: I think i need to replace this    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>    by this    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&region=FR"></script> with An API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api key is missing, as you can see in the console:

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Follwing the configuration page of the documentation: http://gmap3.net/configuration.html

You can load the library with the api key

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&region=GB"></script>
```

Or use the api key when loading the map

```
$.gmap3({
  key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
});
```

Comment: yes i added it with <script> and $.gmap3 but I still have the same problem ?

Comment: the problem was on my google API account, I don't know why my API wasn't active. But now it works thanks for all your help ;D